# how to loop properly in this kind of array situation in PHP?

Tags: php, yii

how to loop and save the data, based from the number of the images of this sample array?

**Objective:**

- save the images in the image table based from how many is inside the array sample
- the image with the "0"(zero) suffix, is  the main image and it should be marked as "main image"

  ```
  $postdata = array
      (
      'key' => 'adsfasdf34234234235235c',
      'source' => 1,
      'maincategoryid' => 12,
      'subcategoryid' => 34,
      'userid' => 6,
      'shopid' => 1,
      'status' => 1,
      'description'=> 'blah blah blah',
      'image0' => 'blahbalh\big.jpg',
      'image1' => 'hblahblah\smal1.jpg',
      'image2' => 'flowers.jpg',
      'image3' => 'leaf.jpg'
  );
  ```

here's my image table table fields

```
IMAGEID,USERID,SHOPID,IMAGEPATH,MAINIMAGE,STATUS
```

the expected input in the table should be something like this based from the sample above

```
IMAGEID,USERID,SHOPID,     IMAGEPATH         ,MAINIMAGE,STATUS
    1     6     1      blahbalh\big.jpg          1        1    
    2     6     1      hblahblah\smal1.jpg       0        1
    3     6     1      flowers.jpg               0        1
    4     6     1      leaf.jpg                  0        1
```

as you can see the first image with zero suffix from the array key, is the main image that has flag in the column

I tried looping using foreach or for loop, but I was only able to save 1 row of data based from that array, when I should be saving 4 rows of data

I tried this

```
$mainimage = 0;
for($i=0; $i < count($postdata); $i++){
     if(!isset($postdata['image'.$i])){
          continue;
       }
      $shopmodel->USERID = $postdata['userid'];
      $shopmodel->SHOPID = $postdata['shopid'];
      $shopmodel->IMAGEPATH = $postdata['image'.$i];
      $shopmodel->MAINIMAGE = $mainimage;
      $shopmodel->STATUS = $postdata['status'];
      if($i == 0 ){
           $shopmodel->MAINIMAGE = 1;
      }
      $shopmodel->save();
}
```

I know there's something really wrong,so how to loop and achieve that objective based from my samples?

Comment: it's an active record, no need to worry about that, the main question is, how to loop properly in that array in order to achieve my main objective?

Comment: the $shopmodel->save(), will save it to the image table, I just named it like that since it's just a sample..the save() function attached to taht variable saves whatever was initialized to the attributes

Comment: it's a typo in my sample. I only removed the letter s

Comment: yes,the main concern is how should I loop properly in order to be able to have that input in my sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wheew, after a few hours of trial and error, I came up with my own solution to fix this issue
here's my solution

```
$ismain = 0;
$images = array();

        for($i=0; $i < count($postdata); $i++){
            if(!isset($postdata['image'.$i])){
                continue;
            }
            array_push($images, $postdata['image'.$i]);
        }

        foreach($images as $key => $image){
            if($key == 0){
                $ismain = 1;
            } else {
                $ismain = 0;
            }
            echo "adid = ". $postdata['shopid']. "; ismain =" .$ismain."; image =". $image."<br/>";

        }
```

note to self: in the actual(real) application code, I instantiated the model inside the foreach loop, and initialized the corresponding attributes.. and then called the save() function of the model..and boom..the output that I want , showed up..thanks for all who tried to help me..but in the end..I helped myself in my own way. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug to know what goes wrong. E.g. do

```
var_dump($postdata['image'.$i]);
```

right before

```
$shopmodel->USERID = $postdata['userid'];`
```

so you will see if your conditions works fine.

Next consider to reset model when used in loop:

```
$model()->unsetAttributes();
```

and check if it typo here or in your code `$shopsmodel` VS `$shopmodel`

Comment: I already edited my sample, there's no actual typo in the real code

Comment: @Yaroslav, this really should have been posted as a comment. It's not really an answer.

Comment: Try to add `var_dump()` as i mention above to debug and share output.

Comment: no need to var_dump(), there is no error in php, my problem is, how to save the data based from my example table diagram, because the way I loop it using for loop, I am only able to save one row from the array

Comment: Do you want to save all records in one query? Not one by one?

Comment: how to do that?, for as long as I can achieve that output from my sample, I think whatever solution you give can help

Comment: If it's ok for you to save one by one your code will work properly. Why do you say that you only able to save one row? You will iterate through array and call `$shopmodel->save();` to each `imageN` array key. If it don't save than you have only one `imageN` key in your `$postdata` or you have other error that prevents you from saving. It's because i want to see if `var_dump()` will print one item or more.

Comment: also if your `$shopmodel` is active record instance i recommend you to reset its values before you will use it again.

Comment: reset?, why should I reset it?, when the start of initialization happens when the for loop starts ,right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61351/discussion-between-yaroslav-and-sasori).